# Scala Slick configure with Amazon X-Ray

Tags: scala, slick, aws-xray

anyone tried to use this:

[X-Ray](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-sqlclients.html)

with Slick ?

```
import slick.dbio.DBIO
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._

private[database] class PostgresConnector extends DatabaseConnector {
protected final val configurationPath = "mycompany.backend.database.postgres"

protected lazy val database = Database.forConfig(configurationPath)
```

Probably no way because its based on tomcat:

> These interceptors are in the aws-xray-recorder-sql-postgres and
> aws-xray-recorder-sql-mysql submodules, respectively. They implement
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor and are compatible with
> Tomcat connection pools.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to instrument a SQL connection using a provider other than MySQL or Postgres, you can try to use the generic JDBC-based SQL Library, documented here: https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java#intercept-jdbc-based-sql-queries

Alternatively, you can use the [X-Ray auto-instrumentation agent for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/aws-x-ray-auto-instrumentation-agent-for-java.html), which automatically captures all JDBC-based SQL queries.